# missing right parenthesis for case statements

Tags: sql, oracle, case, case-when

I'm unable to fit only one condition(in the BOLD) in case statements:

```
Select  pipeline_tx_status from pipeline, Consol
 Where pipeline.pipeline_tx_status = case UPPER('&ps_status') when 'O' then 'O' 
      WHEN 'MFT' then 'MFT'
      WHEN 'IS'  then 'IS'
      **WHEN (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in ('CNF') OR  (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in('OI','ICF','C') AND NVL(MWB_HEADER.ACCOUNTING_STATUS,'O') NOT IN ('O'))) then 'CNF'**
      WHEN  'OI'  then 'OI'
      WHEN  'ICF'  then 'ICF'
      WHEN  'C'    then 'C'
      End;
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Your question is far from clear. Please add the table definitions and explain what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. i just want to fit  **WHEN (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in ('CNF') OR  (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in('OI','ICF','C') AND NVL(MWB_HEADER.ACCOUNTING_STATUS,'O') NOT IN ('O'))) then 'CNF'** under one of the WHEN clause and it is throwing an error: missing right parenthesis. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can use `case` expressions.

1. With values: `case x when a then b when c then d else e end`
2. With boolean expressions: `case when x = a then b when x = c then d else e end`

You can't mix these. You've got the first form, and you're trying to add something that only works in the second form. Convert it to the second form first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply hvd. only problem is, in one of the BI tool it was working and i have to write the same in SQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logic most of the time you're just testing for equality between `pipeline.pipeline_tx_status` and `'ps_status` parameter.  So you could rewrite this to be a normal WHERE condition.

```
Where (p_con.pipeline_tx_status = 'CNF' 
        and UPPER('&ps_status') = p_con.pipeline_tx_status)
or  (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in('OI','ICF','C') 
      AND NVL(MWB_HEADER.ACCOUNTING_STATUS,'O') NOT = 'O'
       and UPPER('&ps_status') = 'CNF' )
or pipeline.pipeline_tx_status = UPPER('&ps_status')
```

---

In a comment you say:

> "in one of the BI tool it was working and i have to write the same in SQL developer"

Either the BI tool was not running against Oracle or the BI tool takes pseudo-SQL and translates it into valid (i.e. compilable) SQL. But however you bounce it the CASE statement you have won't run on Oracle. So your task is to convert the **logic** of the BI tool into something which will run on Oracle. Providing you get the required output it shouldn't matter whether the code is different. Besides, if the original code won't run you have no choice.